# Using Python to ssh with no modules

Tags: python, ssh

I'm in a pickle with writing a script that can SSH into device, run a command and parse that data out to a file. I've written this using Pyparsing and Exscript then I found out that the device I'm going to be using this on is using Python 2.4.4 and Debian 4.1.1 so the modules will not work on this. Now I am back to the drawing board trying to find out how to do this with **NO** modules. Anyone have any reference or point me in the right direction for this? Thank you in advance.

**Here is my code:**

```
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.protocols import SSH2
import uuid
from pyparsing import *
import re
import yaml

account = read_login()              
conn = SSH2()                       
conn.connect('172.0.0.1')     
conn.login(account)           

conn.execute('foobar')
data = conn.response
conn.send('exit\r')               
conn.close()

###### PARSER ######

date_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d-\d\d-\d\d')
time_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d:\d\d:\d\d')
pairs = [{'category': 'General Information',
          'kv': Group(Word(alphanums) + Word(alphanums))},
         {'category': 'Last Reset:',
          'kv': Group(Word(alphas, max=1) + Word(alphas)) + Literal(':').suppress()
                + Group(Regex(date_regex) + Regex(time_regex)
                + Optional(SkipTo(LineEnd())))
          }
         ]
# build list of categories with associated parsing rules
categories = [Word("# ").suppress() + x['category']
               + OneOrMore(Group(x['kv']))
              for x in pairs]
# account for thing you don't have specific rules for
categories.append(Word("#").suppress() + Optional(SkipTo(LineEnd())) +
                  Group(OneOrMore(Combine(Word(alphanums) + SkipTo(LineEnd()))))
                  )
# OR all the categories together
categories_ored = categories[0]
for c in categories[1:]:
    categories_ored |= c
configDef = OneOrMore(categories_ored)
suppress_tokens = ["show all", "SSH>", "Active System Configuration"]
suppresses = [Literal(x).suppress() for x in suppress_tokens]
for s in suppresses:
    configDef.ignore(s)

result = configDef.parseString(data)
for e in result:
    print(e)
with open('/Users/MyMac/development/data.yml', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write( yaml.dump(e))
```

**UPDATE**

I have followed the advice below and now have `Pexpect` installed and found a older version of `Python-Pyparsing` that I have also installed. So I'm on my way again to getting my scripts to work with modules. Thanks!

Comment: How about using `subprocess` to talk to a system `ssh` utility?  `pexpect` looks like an early pure Python module that only needs `pty`.

Comment: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/legacy.html  paramiko is another early pure Python SSH library.

Comment: @hpaulj I was looking into using `subprocess`, but having issues with that connecting and running a command. I looked at `paramiko` before I wrote the script above but had some issues, which is why I went with `Exscript`. I'll look at the early releases of `paramiko` and see if that may work. The other thing is the `debian` is so old and won't let me install modules very easily.

Comment: `pexpect-2.4` is compact enough (I think) to 'install' by just adding one or two files to your own directory.  It doesn't have to be in a system directory.  `paramiko` might need to be in its own directory without yours.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks! I added `pexpect` and have the ability to `ssh` into the device, now hopefully I can find a solution with `pyparsing` or another module.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is already solved, but...

As long as your SSH is configured for this host (or the host doesn't require you to log-in), you should be able to do the following.

```
import os

""" This will execute foobar on the remote host 
and store the command output to a text file
on your machine.""" 
os.system("ssh 172.0.0.1 foobar > ~/data.txt")

""" Commence processing """
data = open("data.txt", mode='r')
# and so on and so on
```

You can also use the `subprocess` library, but `os.system` for these types of tasks is the simplest IMO.